# Mecab output - list of name types

Tags: nlp, translation, pos-tagger, mecab

A sample output from meecab:

```
に   ニ   ニ   に   助詞-格助詞
```

We have `助詞`(particle) as the type and `格助詞` (case-marking particle) as the PoS. Where can I find a list of all possible types and PoS's that mecab uses? I want to be able to map the Japanese to a translated set, without the need to translate it on the fly.

Comment: Something that's helped me understand at least IPADIC's parts-of-speech categories is Ve, which acts as a MeCab post-processor, combining MeCab morphemes into lemmas: https://github.com/Kimtaro/ve/blob/master/lib/providers/mecab_ipadic.rb#L118 is the code that does this. Ve also powers jisho.org (written by the same guy!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this has all the info: http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/doc/postag/, depending on the output selected for mecab.